# Server can't see VLAN after changing an IP of something else

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, vlan

I used to have a 3COM Layer3 switch on our production floor whos IP was 192.168.0.13 and it was creating VLANs and one of them was VLAN5.  I have replaced that switch with a Netgear switch and assigned VLAN creation to the firewall.  When I assign anything on the network a 192.168.0.13 address, I can no longer communicate to VLAN5 from anything connected to the new server rack switch when the port that it is connected to have VLAN traffic tagged.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSsm0.jpg

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand your network structure from your text. Please provide a network diagram, which shows the different VLANs and their IP subnetworks and how they are connected together.

Comment: Yea I will here in a little bit.  I did discover that its anything connected into Switch that the server is connected to who ports are setup to pass VLAN5 traffic cant see.  Anything else can ping it just fine but once I tag VLAN5 through a port when 192.168.0.13 is assigned to something, it can no longer ping VLAN5 devices or the gateway of VLAN5

Comment: I put a link on the OP.  Left config is old and right is new

Answer (score 0):

When you reconnect a server with a VLAN trunk uplink, the new uplink switch port must support the same tagged/untagged VLAN combination, otherwise connection to the associated VLANs is lost. You need to look at the former port's configuration and rebuild that on the replacement port.

Comment: The ports are all setup the same way.  I have 7 servers in my rack and all their ports on the switch they are connected to are setup the same and they dont lose connection to VLAN5 when I assign that old IP to a new device

Comment: Do you see the server's MAC address in VLAN 5 on the switch?

Comment: On the switch the server is connected to I see the MAC and its on VLAN1 because it has a VLAN1 address.  Keep in mind the switch that was pulled was never directly connected to this server.

Comment: You need to see the MAC in VLAN 5 as well if it's supposed to be connected to it. I can't "keep in mind" what you never told us.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you mean by see it in VLAN5 if I dont have address table to bring up and look at.  SHould I be looking at the firewall creating the VLAN5 or the switch that the server is connected to?

Comment: Ok change of plans.  I did some additional digging and any port on the switch that the servers are connected that is tagged with VLAN5, is unable to communicate with VLAN5 if I set something to the 192.168.0.13 IP

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The servers had a manual route setup I didnt know about.  I deleted the manually added routes and everything is working fine when I assign stuff the 0.13 address now.